# zpool import error

Tags: solaris, zfs

I suffered a complete pool failure – the fan in the array chassis stopped working and all drives overheated. After cooling down, all drives checked out ok using seagate's seatools test utility and smartctl showed them ok. I was also able to read directly from each device and the system sees each device.

But… when I tried to bring the pool back online, it's status was UNAVAIL. This is a raidz1 pool with 4 total drives. The error I was getting stated:

```
zpool cannot import pool one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

and zpool status showed:

```
NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM 
pool_01                      UNAVAIL     0     0     1 
  raidz1-0                   DEGRADED    0     0     4 
    c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    ONLINE      0     0     4 
    c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0    ONLINE      0     0     4 
    3743539469189005045      UNAVAIL     0     0     0 
    c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    ONLINE      0     0     4 
logs 
  mirror-1                   ONLINE      0     0     0 
    c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE      0     0     0 
    c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE      0     0     0
```

zpool clear would clear the checksums but not make the pool available. I'd seen similar behavior before and exporting the pool and re-importing it would fix the problem. That was not the case this time. This time, the system refused to import the pool. I could import it with -F, but that brought it back in the same unusable state.

One odd thing… if you look at the output above, there is a device called “3743539469189005045” – I have no idea what this is or why it would be associated with the pool. The actual device that should be listed there is “c0t5000C500A22D9330d0”, which is available and can be directly read from.

Ignoring that for a minute, I figured, this is a raidz1 pool, so I should be able to import it with 3 “ONLINE” drives. Still no. So, in trying everything I could think of, I ran this command:

zpool import -FX pool_01

I'm not sure where I got the “-X" from… it was in my notes, but I can't find any reference to it in the man pages. And, Google isn't much help because now every search about ZFS brings up Linux or FreeBSD instead of Solaris.

The pool consisted of 4x 6TB drives. So, it should be trying to import three of those drives for a total of 18TB of data if it had to scan every block.

The import has been running for 14 days. It's not producing any errors and I can see read/write activity on each of the drives. In general, iostat looks like this:

```
    extended device statistics 
    r/sw/s Mr/s Mw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t %w %b device        
    210.3 70.1 6.7 0.1 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.6 0 15 c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0       
    338.5 129.2 8.1 0.1 0.0 0.4 0.0 0.8 0 28 c0t5000C500A24AD833d0        
    210.3 70.1 6.7 0.1 0.0 0.2 0.0 0.6 0 13 c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0
```

One drive is consistently busier than the other two, but all of the stats change every second, which leads me to believe it's doing something.

If I try to truss the import PID, truss just hangs. The zpool-pool_01 process respawns every second and apparently isn't doing anything since it dies too fast to even get a trace, plus I have no idea what the PID will be.

My question at this point is, what does the -X option do on Solaris? Before I used it, the import would either fail immediately, or import in an UNAVAIL state. Now, the import is running indefinitely. I don't mind letting it run if it's actually doing something and there's a chance of a successful import.

Can I stop it without doing more damage? Is there another way to get this pool online? I'm still confused as to how a 4-disk pool with 3 available disks can fail to come online.

Is there a way to get the 3743539469189005045 device remapped to the actual device (c0t5000C500A22D9330d0), and would that help the pool correct itself?

The system is Solaris x64 11.4.27.0.1.82.1. I understand that there may not be a lot of Solaris-specific experience here anymore, but my hope is that the vast knowledge of ZFS and its history here might be enough for some of you to help me.

I really could use some help here. This array had a lot of data on it that, by my own failure, wasn't backed-up. Critical data was, but still, losing so much non-critical data is going to be painful. 18TB is a lot to back-up and my resources were limited from a backup perspective. Anyway, lesson learned there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### ---UPDATE---

I rebooted the system since I was unable to stop the zpool import (I/O lock I guess). When I try a simple zpool pole (ie. zpool import without specifying a pool name), I get:

```
pool: pool_01 
id: 346760273105473837 
state: UNAVAIL 
status: One or more devices are unavailable. action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data. The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using the '-f' flag. config:

    pool_01                      UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
      raidz1-0                   DEGRADED
        c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    ONLINE
        c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0    ONLINE
        c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
        c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    ONLINE
    logs
      mirror-1                   ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE

device details:

    c0t5000C500A24AD833d0      UNAVAIL        incorrect labeling data
    status: ZFS detected errors on this device.
            The device has bad label or disk contents.
```

Notice how c0t5000C500A24AD833d0 shows up twice -- one is ONLINE and the other is UNAVAIL. Also, the other drive that should be in that list (c0t5000C500A22D9330d0) isn't listed at all.

The format command shows all 4 drives that should be part of the pool:

```
  16. c0t5000C500A22D9330d0 <ATA-ST6000VN0041-2EL-SC61-5.46TB>
      /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c500a22d9330
  17. c0t5000C500A24AD833d0 <ATA-ST6000VN0041-2EL-SC61-5.46TB>
      /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c500a24ad833
  18. c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0 <ATA-ST6000VN0041-2EL-SC61-5.46TB>
      /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c500a232afa6
  19. c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0 <ATA-ST6000VN0041-2EL-SC61-5.46TB>
      /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c500a243c8de
```

'format verify' on each of them returns no errors. The 'format verify' output for each drive looks like this:

```
Volume name = < >
ascii name = <ATA-ST6000VN0041-2EL-SC61-5.46TB>
bytes/sector = 512 sectors = 11721045167
accessible sectors = 11721045134
Part Tag Flag First Sector Size Last Sector
0 usr wm 256 5.46TB 11721028750
1 unassigned wm 0 0 0
2 unassigned wm 0 0 0
3 unassigned wm 0 0 0
4 unassigned wm 0 0 0
5 unassigned wm 0 0 0
6 unassigned wm 0 0 0
8 reserved wm 11721028751 8.00MB 11721045134
```

fmadm shows no faults.

Trying an import with -f, -F, readonly=on and various combinations of those options all fail. Most fail with: cannot import 'pool_01': one or more devices is currently unavailable

An import attempt without any options (ie. zpool import pool_01) returns this error:

```
cannot import 'pool_01': I/O error Destroy and re-create the pool from a backup source.
```

If I remove the D833 drive and do an import, it returns this:

```
pool: pool_01 
id: 346760273105473837 
state: UNAVAIL 
status: One or more devices are unavailable. action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data. config:

    pool_01                      UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      raidz1-0                   UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
        c0t5000C500A22D9330d0    UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
        c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0    ONLINE
        c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    REMOVED
        c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    ONLINE
    logs
      mirror-1                   ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE

device details:

    c0t5000C500A22D9330d0      UNAVAIL        incorrect labeling data
    status: ZFS detected errors on this device.
            The device has bad label or disk contents.
```

Notice here that both drives show up correctly with their respective device identifiers.

If I reinsert the D833 drive and remove the 9330 drive, it shows: pool: pool_01 id: 346760273105473837 state: UNAVAIL status: One or more devices are unavailable. action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data. The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using the '-f' flag. config:

```
pool_01                      UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
  raidz1-0                   DEGRADED
    c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    ONLINE
    c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0    ONLINE
    c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
    c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    ONLINE
logs
  mirror-1                   ONLINE
    c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE
    c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE
```

device details:

```
c0t5000C500A24AD833d0      UNAVAIL        incorrect labeling data
status: ZFS detected errors on this device.
        The device has bad label or disk contents.
```

Notice here it again shows the incorrect device id's. I'm not sure what to make of the fact removing D833 causes all of the devices to report their correct names but having it installed causes confusion between it and 9330.

If I remove them both, it shows:

```
pool: pool_01 
id: 346760273105473837 
state: UNAVAIL 
status: One or more devices are unavailable. action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data. The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using the '-f' flag. config:

    pool_01                      UNAVAIL  incorrect labeling data
      raidz1-0                   DEGRADED
        c0t5000C500A22D9330d0    REMOVED
        c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0    ONLINE
        c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    REMOVED
        c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    ONLINE
    logs
      mirror-1                   ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE
        c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE
```

From what I can tell, all of the disks are perfectly operational. It seems to be a ZFS labeling problem somewhere. At least that's my guess since 'format verify' did not report any disk-level label problems.

It's as if the zpool metadata is messed up and it's identifying two different devices (c0t5000C500A24AD833d0 and c0t5000C500A22D9330d0) as the same device (c0t5000C500A24AD833d0) even though the system clearly sees them as two separate devices.

Is there a way to fix the zpool metadata? I tried zdb but since the pool can't be opened, it just exited with: zdb: can't open pool 'pool_01': I/O error

---

### --- UPDATE 2 ---

I dug a bit deeper over the weekend and compared the zpool labels from each drive.

I used (for example):

```
zdb -ll /dev/dsk/c0t5000C500A24AD833d0s0
```

**NOTE that on Solaris, you must specify slice-0 (d0s0) when looking at the zpool label, if you only specify the device (ie. ...d0   vs.   ...d0s0) it will tell you it can't "unpack the label"**

What I found was a bit unexpected.  All of the labels were consistent except for one, but the one that was inconsistent was on one of the drives that had no complaints registered from it -- drive c0t5000C500A232AFA6d0.  This drive always reported "ONLINE".  So, on a whim, I removed that drive from the array and the pool imported in a DEGRADED state.  I imported it with 'zpool import -R /mnt/x -o readonly=on -f  pool_01'  This looked promising, but those hopes were soon dashed.  When I tried to read files, snapshots, etc. from the array, nearly everything returned  "/path/to/my/file:  I/O error" and the CKSUM numbers on the array started to skyrocket.

The pool looks like this now...

```
  pool: pool_01
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible. Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
        Run 'zpool status -v' to see device specific details.
   see: http://support.oracle.com/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: resilvered 0 in 2m16s with 1 errors on Fri Feb 16 06:32:18 2024

config:

        NAME                         STATE      READ WRITE CKSUM
        pool_01                      DEGRADED      0     0   59K
          raidz1-0                   DEGRADED      0     0  118K
            c0t5000C500A24AD833d0    DEGRADED      0     0  128K
            c0t5000C500A22D9330d0    DEGRADED      0     0  118K
            3743539469189005045      UNAVAIL       0     0     0
            c0t5000C500A243C8DEd0    DEGRADED      0     0  116K
        logs
          mirror-1                   ONLINE        0     0     0
            c0t5F8DB4C095690612d0s0  ONLINE        0     0     0
            c0t5F8DB4C095691282d0s0  ONLINE        0     0     0

errors: 32790 data errors, use '-v' for a list
```

This is a bit frustrating because I've been so focused on the drives reporting UNAVAIL or REMOVED the whole time only to find that the one causing the import to fail was one of the drives that showed no errors or complaints.

My question now is, is the corrupted data the result of using 'import -FX' and letting it run for 2 weeks?   Ie. did I shoot myself in the foot thinking I had no other options when I ran the -X.  Or does it not corrupt data, and the problem is with the drives themselves.... even though they report no hardware-level errors?   And.... if it is the result of the -X, is there any way to recover from it?